# 2D interpolation in matlab

Tags: matlab, 2d, interpolation

I have a 360*3 matrix with column 1 having latitude values column 2 having longitude values and column 3 having gravity values.

The problem is that when I create a grid of latitude and longitude using meshgrid the grid spacing is not constants which is creating problem.

I tried to create a new equally spaced grid of 360 * 360 with min max as same as initially provided latitude and longitude. Now I need to interpolate the gravity values at the newly formed grid.

Please help. I am using interp2 but it is showing error.

```
dt1
x = D(:,1);
y = D(:,2);
g = D(:,3);
xg = linspace(min(x),max(x),360);
yg = linspace(min(x),max(x),360);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(xg,yg);
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(x,y,);
G = interp2(xx,yy,g,X,Y);`
```

Please help

Comment: You should probably supply some example data and show the error.

Comment: Unfortunately `interp2` won't do what you need because it also requires the input data to be equally spaced. The `scatteredinterpolant` class is the one you need.

Answer (score 1):

Several things regarding your code:

- g appear to be of false size, i.e. it should be a matrix of size x/y.
- yg = linspace(min(x),max(x),360); --> yg = linspace(min(y),max(y),360);
- there is a typo in your code at [xx,yy] = meshgrid(x,y,);, the second comma in the meshgrid function yields an error

Then, I tried the following, and it seems to work perfectly fine

```
x=sort(rand(10,1));
y=sort(rand(10,1));
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(x,y);
g=peaks(xx,yy); % the gravity values have to be matrix form
xg=linspace(min(x), max(x), 360);
yg=linspace(min(y), max(y), 360);
[X,Y]=meshgrid(xg,yg);
G=interp2(xx,yy,g,X,Y);
figure
mesh(G)
figure
mesh(g)
```

Provide the data in D(..) to get more help.

Comment: Thankyou for the help the g was creating problem.